# What would my alloy (Marbelar) be made from?

Tags: metals, metalworking, element

Now, I have a fictional alloy called marbelar in my world, having a similar appearance to brass, featuring a reddish-gold appearance. It also has the highest stopping power out of any material in my world, basically, it makes really good armor. What I'm asking is, what would be the materials used to make it, and how effective would it be? Do note that this is for a space age world, so it pretty much has the entire periodic table at its disposal. Basically, look for a light, durable, and strong alloy.

Update: I have changed marbelar from an actual alloy to a subset of Divinitite, my universe's version of handwavium or unobtanium, making this question irrelevent.

Update 2: I just started my chatroom called [The Council Of Devourers](https://i.redd.it/mm12g6gwizl21.jpg), for discussing the creation of my universe.

Update 3: The Council of Devourers is closed now. No further discussion shall occur.

Comment: well you can start by what kinetic energy resistance is. in the real world that would be mass so you are asking what is the heaviest alloy you can make.

Comment: The word *orichalcum* has two meanings: first, it is the normal word used in Latin and Greek for what we call in English *brass*; if your alloy is similar to orichalcum in this (most common) sense, then it is made of copper and zinc. Second, it is used by Plato to refer to an unspecified fantastic metal used by the splendiferous civilization of Atlantis. If your alloy is similar to orichalcum in this (fantastic) sense, then it is obviously made of unobtainium and handwavium. Which is to say, what do you mean when you say that the alloy has *"a similar makeup to orichalcum"*?

Comment: @AlexP there is, in fact, a real life form of orichalcum, independent from brass. Orichalcum is a gold-copper alloy, although in what percentages I do not know.

Comment: The vast majority of gold jewellery and gold coins are made from a gold and copper alloy. Pure gold is called 24 carats; most jewellery is made of 18 carats gold, that is, and alloy containing three quarters gold and one quarter copper. Gold and copper can be alloyed in any proportion, the resulting color varying from yellow to reddish yellow to yellowish red to red. (That is, any gold-copper alloy with at least one half gold is yellow, or at least faintly reddish yellow.)

Comment: @AlexP I am looking for a material that is somewhat of an off gold color. Basically, think of a cross between a gold color and a brass color.

Comment: [Colored gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colored_gold). And maybe bronze (the Romans were fond of gold-ish colored bronze for low denomination coins), or [chemical coloring of metals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_coloring_of_metals).

Comment: @AlexP Reddish seems to fit.

Comment: Based on what little information has been provided in the question and comments, your only choice is a [copper-gold alloy](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/materials-science/gold-alloys). Note that "how effective" is a subjective question that's inappropriate because it depends on conditions you haven't provided (effective against what? water? dragons? lightning? my little sister?). Please remember to provide as much detail as you can and, if possible, specific examples that demonstrate what you're looking for.

Comment: The trouble with gold & copper is they are both soft metals. Individually or combined, they would make poor quality armor (assuming impact strength). A toughening addition would possible be a combination of bismuth, tungsten, vanadium, titanium, chromium, nickel, depleted uranium.

Comment: @fred Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: (Though it's worth noting that even adding toughening metals into the alloy aren't going to give it "the highest stopping power of anything in the world", not if you wish to retain its visual properties.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I have a fictional alloy called marbelar in my world, having a similar makeup to orichalcum,"

Your Marbelar is obviously make out of sintered Quinzanium, with an alloy of Howbenium and Salvarite plating to secure it.

Seriously:
You are asking us for the exact formulation of a Fictional metal, which must be similar to another mythological metal.

I advise you approach the author that invented the Marbelar for their writings, and ask them. And if that person is yourself, then the use of a mirror might be handy.

Here is what wiki has to say about Orichalcum.

> Orichalcum has been held to be either a gold-copper alloy, a copper-tin or copper-zinc brass, or a metal or metallic alloy no longer known.
> In later years, "orichalcum" was used to describe the sulfide mineral chalcopyrite and also to describe brass

That leaves a *lot* of leeway for wandwaving when making something similar. a *lot*.

Comment: Marbelar is actually something of my own creation. I guess I may just have to work it out myself then.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the material described as "orichalcum" historically is just a different variety of brass. The properties you've ascribed to your Marbelar, @Korblox, are completely unlike brass - or a gold-copper alloy.  It wouldn't make good armour or weapons.  Your alloy is imaginary.

Comment: @jdunlop I've changed the question a bit.